# I have trouble accessing my Mac

Tags: keyboard, password, filevault

After I accidentally left my Mac on my balcony last summer and after a heavy rain when typing the mac keyboard only symbols appear.

When using external keyboard things have worked smoothly since until today when I turned on Filevault.

Now suddenly it wouldn't accept my password any longer.

Now I can only access the guest account on my mac.

And the Mac wont recognize my password even after the restore password--- nothing happens in keyboard when i try to type these passwords.

I have even tried resetting the PRAM but it would not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you do not like my edit let me know.

Comment: What do you want to know? How to save your data? Obviously you should have your keyboard fixed...

Answer (score 1):

What Mac are you using (Macbook Air / Pro)? Does it have a replaceable disk?

If the disk is not replaceable, I see the following options:

- *Assuming the* `T` *key is still functional:* Access your Mac in [target mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1661) and unlock the disk from the other computer. For example [this article](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/using-disk-utility-to-unlock-or-decrypt-your-filevault-2-encrypted-boot-drive/) explains the procedure.
- *Assuming the* `cmd` *and* `R` *keys are still functional:* [Recovery Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4811)
- *Assuming the* `alt` *key is still functional:* Same as above, but you [manually select](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1310) the recovery partition

Sometimes the filevault2 volume cannot be opened easily. See [here](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/mac-os-x-10-8-4s-recovery-hd-removes-ability-to-decrypt-filevault-2-encrypted-mac/) for a workaround.

If the disk is replaceable I would remove it asap, unlock the disk, and save the data e.g. with an USB-IDE adapter (like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812232002) one).